# SQL SERVER: SELECT TOP 1 entire row into "ROW" variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to store the entire row as a result of the SELECT TOP * into a kind of "datarow" variable because later, depending on some condition, I need to insert this entire row to a temporary table.

For example, I have done below. The problem is that first I have to assign the values resulting from select top 1 * to variables and then using all these variables to insert into the temporary table, so I want to avoid this, I would like to insert the entire row of select top 1 * into the temporary table at once, see below.

**Current scenario**:

```
DECLARE @Field1 varchar(50)
DECLARE @Field2 int
DECLARE @Field3 DateTime

CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(Field1 varchar(50),  Field2 int, Field3 DateTime)

SELECT TOP 1 @Field1 = field1, @Field2 = field2, @Field3 = field3 from OneTable

// EXECUTE STORE PROCEDURE
DECLARE @ReturnValue int
EXEC @ReturnValue=MySp @Field1

IF @ReturnValue > 0
   INSERT INTO #tmpTbl (Field1, Field2, Field3)
          VALUES (@Field1, @Field2, @Field3)
```

And I would like to do something like this, if possible:

**Desired scenario**:

```
DECLARE @Row SOME_KIND_OF_DATA_ROW_VARIABLE

SET @Row = SELECT TOP 1 field1, field2, field3 from OneTable

// EXECUTE STORE PROCEDURE
DECLARE @ReturnValue int
EXEC @ReturnValue=MySp @Field1

IF @ReturnValue > 0
   INSERT INTO #tmpTbl (Field1, Field2, Field3)
          VALUES @Row <-- Obviously, this is incorrect, but I would like to insert the entire row at once
```

Comment: You can use a table-typed variable. Why though? What are you trying to do? There is probably a set-baset solution that doesn't require keeping track of rows or using temporary tables.

Comment: For example, both INSERT and UPDATE allow you to access modified values through the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, even return them as if they were `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 1):

If the time that the row is extracted isn't important (i.e. you can `SELECT` it out within the `IF` block happily), you can use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` combination to achieve the desired effect with something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(Field1 varchar(50),  Field2 int, Field3 DateTime)

--EXECUTE STORE PROCEDURE
DECLARE @ReturnValue int
EXEC @ReturnValue=MySp @Field1

IF @ReturnValue > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpTbl (Field1, Field2, Field3)
    SELECT TOP 1 field1, field2, field3 from OneTable
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any @Row variable. Just use `insert into ... select....`

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(Field1 varchar(50),  Field2 int, Field3 DateTime)

INSERT INTO #tmpTbl (Field1, Field2, Field3)
SELECT TOP 1 
       field1, field2, field3 
from OneTable
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for... Before inserting row I need to check some condition by calling stored procedure. If condition is satisfied then I insert into the temporary table, if not, I do not insert.

Comment: @user1624552 - you're taking a very *procedural* approach to solving your problem which isn't a good fit for where SQL databases work well. I.e. you're splitting things down into "first I'll do X, then I'll do Y, then I'll do Z". SQL works best if you can give it the whole problem to be solved (as a single query) and let *it* work out how best to solve it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I know but in my case this is impossible to do it in the manner you say. I have tried it but it is not possible. This a little example, but not my exact real case. Of course, the best way is to do in the same select, using joins, and even in combination with cte if needed, but in my case is not possible.I have a stored procedure which is not mine and I cannot touch. If this store procedure were a scalar o tabular function then my problem will be solved by calling the function in a single select that do all, but you cannot call a stored procedure from a select.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ... also you cannot call a stored procedure from a function, well it's is possible but not recomended because it generates side effects. In my case I have a stored procedure that is the condition that decides if the row is taken or not over a set of rows and then I need to union it with a second set of rows.  First set of rows is not within second set of rows and vice versa. The final result must have columns from first and second sets of rows. In my post I haven't told anything about the final union.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Basically the problem that force me to proceed in a procedural way is what I have told in the previous comment but the great culprit is the stored procedure, I cannot touch and change it into a function, it's not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT Aux.Field1, Aux.Field2, Aux.Field3
    INTO #tmpTbl
    FROM  ( SELECT TOP 1 Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM OneTable ) Aux
```

By doing this you will create #tmpTbl, if it already exists, you will have to DROP before creating it again.

Comment: The same I have said to TriV.